# Webview not opening up in my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webview

When I open my extension uncompiled (using an iframe where there should be a webview tag), the app works fine. When I make the iframe into a webview and compile, the webview does not show up.
popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
<body>
<webview id="foo" src="http://www.google.com/" style="width:640px; height:480px"></webview>
</body>
</html>
```

manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["webview"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far webview tag api has been available only to the chrome apps (judging by the fact that there is no mention off webview in Extension API page). So currently, you can't use it in extensions or legacy packaged apps.